# Что означает "двоеточие равно" (:=) Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что означает "двоеточие равно" (:=) Python?

Есть достаточно большой [PEP 572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/), но информации здесь я не нашел.

Comment: Опять для любителей закрывать односложные простые вопросы. Однозначный ответ можно дать, вопрос задан для наполнения ресурса и возможности найти информацию на русском языке. Обратитесь на Мету, если у вас возникает желание закрыть

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/26000198/10562663

Comment: [Некоторые примеры использования оператора](https://habr.com/ru/company/ncloudtech/blog/688032/)

Comment: Вообще, это не "односложный вопрос", и уж точно он требует не односложного ответа. И ответы все будут сводиться к примерам на базе того же PEP 572. Желание закрывать такие вопросы возникает из-за смутного сомнения в том, что автор вопроса не поленился почитать документацию самостоятельно.

Comment: @strawdog мне ответ не нужен, я могу и на английском почитать. Мотивация заключается в том, чтобы иметь данную тему на русском. Если вы считаете, что здесь не место для таких вопросов, голосуйте за закрытие. А я не буду создавать больше таких вопросов

Answer (score 3):

это моржовый язык :)
он позволяет использовать переменные, объявленные в той же сущности/структуре/строчке кода (не знаю как лучше это назвать)

например:

```
x = (a:=2, 3 + a)
```

на выходе даст (2, 5)

позволяет делать некоторые вещи в 1 строчку, вместо нескольких строк

Comment: Ага, в английской терминологии _the walrus operator_, буквально "оператор-морж" )

Answer (score 1):

Еще пример.

В новой версии, мы можем вызывать функцию (get_user), присвоить ее переменной (user) и тут же проверить есть что-то в переменной (user) и если есть, идти под это условие, где и дальше будет доступна заполненная переменная (user).

Функция (demonstration_old_version) делает то же самое, но в старой версии.

```
def get_user(user_id: str):
    if user_id.isdigit():
        return f'UserObj - {user_id}'


def demonstration_walrus_operator(x):
    if user := get_user(x):
        print(user)
    else:
        print('User not found')


def demonstration_old_version(x):
    user = get_user(x)
    if user:
        print(user)
    else:
        print('User not found')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Walrus operator')
    demonstration_walrus_operator('some user')
    demonstration_walrus_operator('123')

    print('\nOld version')
    demonstration_old_version('some user')
    demonstration_old_version('123')
```

Результат выполнения будет

```
Walrus operator
User not found
UserObj - 123

Old version
User not found
UserObj - 123
```